# I need to run a project build using selenium webdriver/maven/junit with jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, jenkins

I have a selenium webdriver live project build using maven and junit framework. I want to run this using jenkins. I google searched but was able to find information when the project is build using testng. I need this information for junit framework.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Note: I am using eclipse mars, so maven is installed automatically.

Comment: Good question. I would like to know answer. Can you please tell what kind of approaches you have done?

Comment: Do you run your project with JAVA main class or with JUnit @Before?

Comment: I have built the automation using maven using JUnit fremework.

Comment: I have downloaded the jenkins war file from the jenkins website and ran it in command prompt using command java -jar jenkins.war. Rem: jenkins.war is the name of teh jenkins war. Now after the command got executed, you can run the url localhost:8080, you can find jenkins running. I am not sure how to run the project I have built in JUnit to run using jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found below mentioned post to be highly useful to get my problem resolved

http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/5189/install-maven-into-eclipse#a5303

This site gives step-by-step instructions for Eclipse 4.5 Mars/4.4 Luna, with lots of screenshots. Detailed instructions on installing as an embedded module or a standalone application and then configuring Eclipse to use Maven are given.

When I followed the instructions I was able to use the configuration I set up to get my Jenkins builds working.

Comment: It's great that you found an answer to your problem and posted it here, but could you please do two things to make this a good answer - first, edit your answer so it gives the important information from your link, then accept this answer. I will give you a starting point by editing your answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

With Jenkins you can execute shell commands. I would just execute the Maven command you would use locally to run the tests on your own computer. Maybe something like: `mvn clean test`

> Using Jenkins built-in "Execute Windows batch command" you can run
>   commands using the windows shell.
>
> Using Jenkins built-in "Execute shell" you can run commands using unix
>   shell

Comment: Can please share more details or link ? Because I have maven project also.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow the below approach

- Create a main method to invoke your test
- Use Maven for managing dependencies and create an Ant build file to run your main method
- Install Ant plugin in Jenkins
- Define workspace and build file while creating a Jenkin job. Specify time if you wish to run the test automatically at a given time/durations OR run the Jenkin job manually from Jenkins console

If you do not want to use Ant, you may create a jar file for your framework and run the jar directly by creating a Jenkins job that executes the jar file